# Evitar que al recargar una pagina vuelva a crear el mismo registro

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Como evito que si al recargar la pagina a la que es re direccionado un usuario luego de agregar un registro en laravel 5.3 se vuelva a crear el mismo registro? la idea es que no lo haga, pero en caso de que el usuario refresque la pantalla por algún motivo no se vuelva a crear el mismo registro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias soluciones posibles para este problema típico, voy a escribirte algunas de ellas:

- Si tienes algún campo único por cada registro (por ejemplo una dirección de correo electrónico, un identificador del tipo que sea, un número de teléfono, etc.) puedes utilizar la validación `unique` y evitarías dicho problema.
- En el controlador (incluso podría ser un tipo de validación en el request) puedes comparar (o delegar la comparación) el último registro insertado en la base de datos por ese usuario (asumiendo que se requiera estar registrado para registrar esa información) con los datos que intentas ingresar de nuevo al recargar y determinar si son válidos o no según tus reglas.
- Tal vez el más sencillo: hacer una redirección a otra ruta después de guardar los datos, de esa forma si la persona recarga la página, simplemente estará haciendo un simple GET.

Un ejemplo del último punto, para el cual necesitas tres rutas:

```
// muestras el formulario de creación
public function create()
{
    // hacer otras cosas
    return view('articulo.crear');
}

// almacenas el registro
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // guardarlo ...
    return redirect()->route('articulo.creado', ['id' => $id]);
    // o puedes redirigir a un dashboard, o al home, lo que quieras
}

// muestras una página informando que fue creado
public function created($id)
{
    // obtener datos?
    return view('articulo.creado', compact('articulo'));
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, utilice la del campo unique y me funciono.

Answer (score 0):

no se como funciona larabel, pero en lo personal cuando quiero evitar que el usuario tenga la posibilidad de que refresque la pagina, utilizo un redirect, y paso los valores requeridos por parametros.